# PrimeNG theme font overwriting Angular application font

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, primeng, angular-components

I am trying to use PrimeNG on my angular application with Nova Light theme. I added the dependency and added `theme.css` file to `styles.scss` file as shown below. Here is the problem, PrimeNG theme over writes my application font despite specifying font in `styels.scss` file

**styles.scss**

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

//PrimeNg theme and libraries
@import "~primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";

@import  "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import  "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";


//@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme.css";

body
{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #F7F6F3;
}
```

Comment: why you are using primeng with angular material ??

Comment: I am using PrimeNG table

Comment: overwrite CSS of it, using body {font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;}

Comment: I actually did it. See my `styles.scss` file. It didn't work

Answer (score 12):

Modify your CSS `body` rule to also override PrimeNG's default font rule by adding `body .p-component`:

```
body,
body .p-component
{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #F7F6F3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this piece of code in Style.css:

```
body,
body .p-component {
   font-size: 11px !important;
}

.p-component, .p-component *{
   font-size: 11px !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeng is using the css variables for font. If you set as below in your style.scss then it will work

`--font-family: "Open Sans";`

Your new CSS would be:

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

//PrimeNg theme and libraries
@import "~primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";

@import  "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts";
@import  "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";


//@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/material.theme.css";

--font-family: "Open Sans";

body
{
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #F7F6F3;
}
```